# Cannot generate unified Allure report from two separate Jenkins maven builds

Tags: maven, jenkins, report, allure

I want to generate a unified report by merging the results from two separate Jenkins maven projects (and I've read that Allure does support that feature - to merge results different allure-results folders), but it does not work properly as I'll explain below.

My objective is to have visibility from all tests results I've from all projects. Currently I can only see the test results specific to a project.

This is the context:

I've two Maven projects (for `testNG`) running and reporting results via allure on JENKINS. As you can see below, the allure results from those two builds are  working as expected - automatically generated by Allure Jenkins plugin version 2.26.0

[Allure Jenkins plugin working fine for separate maven jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmIQd.png)

Now I've also installed the Allure 2.6.0 and added it on system PATH and properly configure ALLURE_HOME environment var.
So when I ran this command here: 
allure serve `"C:\Users\tester\workspace\scripts-qa\STF\allure-results" --host "127.0.0.1" --port "8081"`

It works perfectly to report the results in my Allure-results from my IntelliJ, as you can see below.

[Allure serve results from my local worspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIbD7.png)

Now when I ran similar command as above one to generate a unified report by merging both reports I got in Jenkins - just the execution trend is been populated - but the total number of tests and its details are not as you can see below.
This is the command I'm executing to generate a unified report:
allure serve `"C:\Users\tester\.jenkins\workspace\Regression2\allure-report" "C:\Users\tester\.jenkins\workspace\Regression1\allure-report" --host "127.0.0.1" --port "8081"`

[Allure problem when trying to merge reports from two separate jenkins projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRCNH.png)

Could you please help me to figure out what is wrong here? Is that possible that allure binary cannot serve results generated by allure Jenkins plugin? If yes, what is the work around to fix that?

Thank you!!
Jean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you are trying to generate cumulative report from already generated reports, which is not correct - Allure needs raw `allure-results` to generate report

As a workaround, you need

1. Archive `allure-results` for each test execution job and attach it to build as artifact
2. Copy `allure-results` artifacts
3. Unzip it
4. Build a report based on `allure-results` from artifacts

Below are code snippets for Pipeline job

Attach `allure-results` as artefact:

```
zip archive: true, dir: "target/allure-results", glob: '', zipFile: "allure-results.zip"
```

Copy artefacts to another job:

```
copyArtifacts filter: 'allure-results.zip', optional: true, projectName: "Regression1", selector: lastCompleted(), target: "Regression1"
unzip dir: "Regression1", glob: '', zipFile: "Regression1/allure-results.zip"
...
```

Build report

```
allure serve Regression1 Regression2
```

Comment: Hi @dmitry-mayer, does it means that with this provided workaround is still possible to generate cumulative report from already generated reports?

If yes, I'm facing issues running the pipeline job with the provided code snippets. 

The errors I'm getting are `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'lastCompleted'` or `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'copyArtifacts' found among steps`

Comment: I’d like to note that Allure cannot combine two already processed reports(allure-report). You can re-open each of them, but cannot combine. That’s why I suggest to store as artifacts raw allure-results and then use it to generate combined reports. Steps copyArtifact and zip/unzip may require additional Jenkins plugins to be installed: Copy Artifact plugin and Pipeline Utility Steps plugin

Comment: Oh ok got it now! I just realized that raw-results are still on its respective workspaces, but in a different folder, so I'm able to get then and generate a consolidate report from different projects! Thank you very much for clarifying my question!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also select reports for aggregation like this:

```
allure includeProperties: false, jdk: '', results: [
        [path: '../name-of-job-1/target/allure-results'],
        [path: '../name-of-job-2/target/allure-results'],
        [path: '../name-of-job-3/target/allure-results']]
    }
```