# How to integrate selenoid and allure

Tags: allure, selenoid

We implement farm of browsers based on [GGR + Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/ggr). If there any instruction how to integrate Allure reporting with such infrastructure?

- On which host allure-results folder will be generated?
- Should I create a script that will go through each selenoid host and copy a
  folder with results to one node?
- How to not mix results from different test runs / CI jobs?

Comment: HIi @Anton I'm trying to achieve GGR+selenoid setup for my project but facing some difficulty can you please help with that. you can track my issue using this link : https://github.com/aerokube/ggr/issues/307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Selenoid is just a Selenium API and has nothing to do with automated tests reports.

2) Allure test execution results are usually generated on the server where your tests are being executed (e.g. on CI-server). Allure report from these results can be either generated on the same server or you could copy results to another server and generate HTML report there. There are a lot of ways to do this depending on your infrastructure.

Comment: got you. Thanks! also this link might help to do what you describe. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50562351/1932373

Answer (score 0):

Use the Allure docker container and send the results using API.
https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service#send-results-through-api