# Only one Parallel Generated in different workspaces Allure Report linked on Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, allure

I expect that two reports generated in different workspaces should be displayed
Why only one Parallel Generated in different workspaces Allure Report linked on Build?

Allure Report Build Logs:

```
Report successfully generated to C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\dir_v1.0\allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.


[dir_v2.0] $ C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\Allure_2.24.1\bin\allure.bat generate C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\dir_v2.0\build\allure-results -c -o C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\dir_v2.0\allure-report
Report successfully generated to C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\dir_v2.0\allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
```

Short Pipeline Script with Parallel Generated Allure Reports in different workspaces:

```
#!groovy

package com.jenkins

def getBrowserTests(browserName, browserVersions) {
  return browserVersions.collectEntries {
    version -> [
      (version): {
        node("docker") {
          ws("${testName}_${version}") {
            stage("${testName}_${version} Tests") {
              script {
                try {
                  bat "echo Testing the ${testName}_${version} browser"
                  bat "gradle test -Dname=remote_${testName} -Dversion=${version}"
                  allure([
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results: [
                      [path: 'build/allure-results']
                    ]
                  ])
                } catch (ignored) {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

def test1_versions = params.test1_versions.split("\n")

def test2_versions = params.test2_versions.split("\n")

pipeline {
  agent {
    label "docker"
  }

  tools {
    gradle "gradle"
  }

  parameters {
    booleanParam(name: 'test1', defaultValue: true, description: '')
    text(name: 'test1_versions', defaultValue: '1.0\n2.0\n3.0\n', description: '')
    booleanParam(name: 'test2', defaultValue: false, description: '')
    text(name: 'test2_versions', defaultValue: '1.0\n2.0\n3.0\n', description: '')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        bat "echo build"
      }
    }
    stage('Tests') {
      parallel {
        stage('Tests 1') {
          when {
            expression {
              return params.test1
            }
          }
          steps {
            script {
              parallel getBrowserTests("tests1", test1_versions)
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Tests 2') {
          when {
            expression {
              return params.test2
            }
          }
          steps {
            script {
              parallel getBrowserTests("tests2", test2_versions)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Screenshots from Jenkins whicg displayed two workspaces and displaying only one report in the build:

[image]

Displayed Allure Report opend by path:

```
http://localhost:8080/job/remote-pipeline/248/allure/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would call it an expected behavior - Allure plugin knows nothing about the second (or any other parallel) stage, so it just reports the results to the build (and there already were any, they will be overridden).

You can merge the test results, put it to the same place (e.g. using `stash` step if we don't talk dozens of MBs, or by copying artifacts), and pass it to `allure` call. Or just make them accessible on a single agent by unique paths and pass them all to `allure`.

Comment: Why doesn't Allure know about the different stages? After all, it generates reports for each stage. But the artifact is displayed only one.

Comment: Stages are running independently from each other, in different workspaces, by different executors (thus, potentially even on different agents). So there are several independent invocations of Allure plugin, each of them within an independent stage. I think your case is the same as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555324/cannot-generate-unified-allure-report-from-two-separate-jenkins-maven-builds). P.S. in my answer, when I wrote `junit`, I meant `allure`, now I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Yes as Alexander mentioned allure doesnt know about other stages, you can use stash in the "post", "always" in jenkins script and stash it like this:

```
parallel {
    stage('Tests 1') {
      when {
        expression {
          return params.test1
        }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          parallel getBrowserTests("tests1", test1_versions)
        }
      }
      post {
        always {
          stash includes: '{path to allure results}', name: 'stash_name_1'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Tests 2') {
      when {
        expression {
          return params.test2
        }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          parallel getBrowserTests("tests2", test2_versions)
        }
      }
      post{
        always {
          stash includes: '{path to allure results}', name: 'stash_name_2'
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always{
      {unstash 'stash_name_1'}
      {unstash 'stash_name_2'}
      allure includeProperties: false, results: [[path to allure results]]
    }
  }
```

doing this will add all the resuts to one workspace, I believe this is what you expected.

Comment: This will only create the stashes. Afterwards, e.g. in the final post always stage, one would need to `unstash` them into two **separate** destinations, and then specify **both** in allure arguments.